# Unique page for each row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, row, unique, creation

I have a table in MySQL. I want to create a new file in my directory, to each row will have a unique page. The only problem, is that many rows are related to the same user, (same ID). I want to make sure users will only see their pages. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: so if you have 100 users you want to generate 100 or more html-files which are only accessible by the corresponding user? about the unique thing. Do a group by or add distinct (depending on your table layout)

Comment: Well in fact I want to generate a php page for each event (my table contains events), and not for each user. The pages must only be accessible for the user that crated the event.

Comment: ok... why dont you make general eventpage and just fill that one with data from the database? Would save you a lot time and trouble. The page would when be accessed like `yoursite.com/events.php?event_id=123` when you could wrap all up with just one query and the session of the user

Comment: Sorry just deleted my comment. Same thought with @Soundz. It would be better the scenario for this. Is the user required to click something? or view their details if yes , then Soundz idea fits on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess file and virtual address like:
www.site.com/128.html
htaccess code for up address is:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index.php?user_id=$1 [L]
```

You can check user id with $_GET['user_id'] variable.

Comment: You're sure it's not dangerous to play in .htaccess?

Comment: If you want user only see their page,don't use this way.Just creat one php file and use session to validate user.